# incorrect usage of union and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a massive SQL Statement and after upgrading to MySQL 5.7 I get the following error:

> incorrect usage of union and limit

This is the initial query:

```
SELECT    tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.*,
          helper.*
FROM      tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca
LEFT JOIN tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper AS helper
ON        tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid = helper.finca_uid
WHERE     hidden=0
AND       deleted=0
AND       helper.persons =
          (
                 SELECT IF(Min(shelper.persons) IS NULL, 1000, Min(shelper.persons)) as tb1
                 FROM   tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper                  AS shelper
                 WHERE  shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid limit 1
                 UNION
                          (
                                 SELECT max(shelper.persons)                        AS tb1
                                 FROM   tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper AS shelper
                                 WHERE  shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid limit 1 )
                 ORDER BY tb1 ASC limit 1)
AND       uid IN
          (
                 SELECT uid_local
                 FROM   tx_wbfincas_finca_category_mm
                 WHERE  uid_foreign=4)
GROUP BY  uid
ORDER BY  min_price ASC ;

https://pastebin.com/H2eaNzJ6
```

I already tried to insert more parentheses, like this:

```
SELECT    tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.*,
          helper.*
FROM      tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca
LEFT JOIN tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper AS helper
ON        tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid = helper.finca_uid
WHERE     hidden=0
AND       deleted=0
AND       helper.persons =
          ((SELECT IF(Min(shelper.persons) IS NULL, 1000, Min(shelper.persons)) as tb1
                    FROM   tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper                  AS shelper
                    WHERE  shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid limit 1 )
                 UNION
                 (SELECT max(shelper.persons) as tb1
                         FROM   tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper AS shelper
                         WHERE  shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid limit 1 )
                 ORDER BY tb1 ASC limit 1)
AND       uid IN
          (SELECT uid_local
                 FROM   tx_wbfincas_finca_category_mm
                 WHERE  uid_foreign=4)
GROUP BY  uid
ORDER BY  min_price ASC ;

https://pastebin.com/mctaxTNL
```

But then I get another error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A code dump this large requires a problem statement to be answerable.  Off the top of my head, I would bet that we could get rid of at least some of those nested subqueries.

Comment: What are you trying to archive with this Select... Union... Select? What you expect to be the result?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `limit`, you need parentheses around the subqueries.  And, `UNION` is not part of the `SELECT` syntax . . . so  you need `SELECT . . . FROM` with a subquery.  So this might work:

```
 helper.persons = (SELECT tbl1
                   FROM ((SELECT IF(Min(shelper.persons) IS NULL, 1000, Min(shelper.persons)) as tb1
                          FROM tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper shelper
                    WHERE shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid 
                          LIMIT 1
                         ) UNION 
                         (SELECT max(shelper.persons)                        AS tb1
                          FROM   tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper shelper
                          WHERE shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid 
                          LIMIT 1
                         )
                        ) x
                 ORDER BY tb1 ASC 
                 LIMIT 1
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solution: 
I had to remove the first limit in the nested Query right before Union.

Query:

```
SELECT tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.*, helper.*   
FROM tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca 
LEFT JOIN tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper as helper 
ON tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid = helper.finca_uid 
WHERE hidden=0 
AND deleted=0 
AND helper.persons = 
    ( 
        SELECT IF(MIN(shelper.persons) IS NULL, 1000, MIN(shelper.persons)) AS tb1 
        FROM tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper AS shelper 
        WHERE shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid 
        UNION 
            ( 
                SELECT MAX(shelper.persons) AS tb1 
                FROM tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca_searchhelper AS shelper 
                WHERE shelper.finca_uid = tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid LIMIT 1 
            ) 
                ORDER BY tb1 ASC LIMIT 1 
    )

AND uid IN 
       (
           SELECT uid_local 
           FROM tx_wbfincas_finca_category_mm 
           WHERE uid_foreign=4
      ) 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY min_price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my second try was with more parentheses. 
With your Query i get

```
Unknown column 'tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca.uid' in 'where clause'
```

Your first select should be "SELECT tb1" and not tbl1 - am i right?

Should i join also the tx_wbfincas_domain_model_finca in the subqueries?